# Generic exception handler prevents specific exception being handled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I have a spring boot application and there I handle exceptions. I have two exception handler methods for now:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public final BaseResponse<GenericException> handleGenericExceptions(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ....
        return response;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public final BaseResponse<MyCustomException> handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ....
        return response;
    }
}
```

At some point, I throw a MyCustomException exception, but when I debug I see that it is handled by handleGenericExceptions method. If I delete handleGenericExceptions method, then it is handled by handleMyCustomException message.

I want MyCustomException to be handled by handleMyCustomException method, and all other exceptions by handleGenericExceptions method. MyCustomException class extends Throwable. What is wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but I do not now why this is the case.

MyCustomException class was extending Throwable, I changed it to extend RunTimeException instead. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 repuatations,so I answered here, hope it make sense.

Throwable class have two important subclass ,Error  and Exception .  your  MyCustomException  extend  Throwable. In spring , if your code  throws  which extends  Throwable , Spring defaultly will decorate it as an IllegalStateException!  I  see this  in spring4.3 source code , if you want  to prove this , you add  @ExceptionHandler({IllegalStateException}) and make your MyCustomException  unmodified , this method will catch it!

Above  evidence is in org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod#doInvoke.

By the way , we  usually throw Exception by extends RuntimeException , why you want to throw  an Throwable .